# Discord bot help command com Command handler

Tags: javascript

É possível fazer um comando de ajuda onde ele busca um elemento do `module.exports`

tipo... `module.exports = { name: 'help', description: '...', execute(message, args){ }`

e dentro do `execute(message, args){ (aqui) }` buscar o name do `module.exports` de todos os outros arquivos de comando da pasta commands incluindo desse arquivo e juntar todos num Embed?

Lembrando q eu estou usando um command handler com fs...

````
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandsFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'help'){
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login(token);```

e a base de comando é 
```module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "This is a Help command!",
    execute(message, args){
        



    }
}```
````

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1):

confuso e pouco especifico, mas acho que entendi...
isso não parece muito seguro, mas...

você pode enumerar os arquivos e carrega-los em um objeto...

```
const fs = require('fs'), path = require('path')
var comandos = {};
fs.readdirSync("./comandos").forEach(file => {
 file = "./comandos"+path.sep+file;
 if (!fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
  var comando = require(file);
  comandos[comando.name] = comando;
 }
});
```

Então poderia verificar se o comando existe e chamar com:

```
if (comandos[name])
 comandos[name].execute(...args);
else
 responder(`${name} não é um comando válido`);
```

e para a função help, usar o **getOwnPropertyNames**:

```
var helpstring = 'Comandos:\n'+Object.getOwnPropertyNames(comandos)
 .map((name)=>` - ${name} - ${comandos[name].description}`)
 .join('\n');
```

para o objeto comandos ser acessível de qualquer arquivo:

```
module.exports = comandos;
var comandos = require('../comandos.js');
```

ou com **global** embora não seja recomendado, iria dispensar o require()

```
global.comandos = comandos
comandos...
```

(... e não vi nada especifico da api discord.js na questão)

Comment: Entao, eu estou fazendo um Command Handler, e acho q ```module.exports = comandos;
var comandos = require('../comandos.js');``` nao funciona com o command handler pq e um arquivo .js para cada comando dentro da pasta de comandos

Comment: a primeira linha é um exemplo para exporta, e a segunda para importa, os arquivos carregados por require um vez são armazenados em cache, então não tem problema algum ficar chamando o arquivo com a lista repetidas vezes para o desempenho @pulse ... '../'  é para acessar a pasta superior, esse require era um exemplo, do comando 'help' chamando ele, <comandos.js><main.js>[pasta comandos/ <help.js>]